# How can i get list of news from database with comments

Tags: php, android, json

i'm going to make news app for android. i made json_encode to my php file. but i just want to add comments in while. i was search it everywhere but i coulnt find. can you please help me.

Here is my php code

```
if (!empty($result)) {

        // check for empty result
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $response["success"] = true;

            $response["news"] = array();
            while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $news = array();
            $news["id"] = $row->id;
            $news["title"] = $row->title;
            $news["details"] = $row->short;
            $news["thumbURL"] = $thumb.$row->images;
            $news["LargeImageURL"] = $big.$row->images;

            array_push($response["news"], $news);
            }

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no news found
            $response["success"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "No news found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no news found
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "No news found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

and i want to add item's comments like in photo

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnaOJ.jpg

Comment: Can you include your code in the question rather than with image links.

Comment: Make a `while`-loop in that `while`-loop. That way you can fetch every comment `for each` item.

Comment: i cant do that. when i put while in while its only show at last item. i dont know how to make for per items.

Comment: @IsmailAltunören If you create an array before the loop and push the populated array into the empty array on each iteration you should have an array of arrays containing your data.

Comment: i try. but i cant show comments. only shows "comment": ""  empty for it. can you please edit my codes with working version. Regards  @piddl0r

Answer (score 0):

I found and its work good. Thanks for your helping.

```
if (!empty($result)) {

        // check for empty result
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $response["success"] = true;

            $response["news"] = array();
            while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $commentsql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comment where cid='".$row->id."' order by id desc limit 0,10");
            $comments = array();
            while($comm = $commentsql->fetch_object()){
            $comments[] = array(
                'id'    => $comm->id,
                'text'  => $comm->comment
                );
            }
            $news = array();
            $news["id"] = $row->id;
            $news["title"] = $row->title;
            $news["details"] = $row->short;
            $news["thumbURL"] = $thumb.$row->images;
            $news["LargeImageURL"] = $big.$row->images;
            $news["comment"] = $comments;

            array_push($response["news"], $news);
            }

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no news found
            $response["success"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "No news found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no news found
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "No news found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```